# How do I change the Mobile Country Code (MCC) in the Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, mcc, mobile-country-code

My Android application needs to react differently to different Mobile Country Codes.

It seems like it is hardcoded to **mcc310 (US)**.  I can read this value from `TelephonyManager.getSimCountryIso()` or by using a resource folder like `res/values-mcc123/` but how do I set this value in the emulator?

Answer (score 18):

To change what `TelephonyManager.getSimCountryIso()` returns, simply execute

```
adb shell setprop gsm.sim.operator.iso-country no
```

and it now returns no (Norway).

If you want to change what `TelephonyManager.getSimOperator()` returns (MCC+MNC) then execute

```
adb shell setprop gsm.sim.operator.numeric 24201
```

and you have changed MCC to 242 (Norway) and MNC to 01 (Telenor).

To see which other properties you can change then execute

```
adb shell getprop
```

This is verified to work on both AVD and Genymotion. However, this does not change these properties persistently.

Comment: This works! Great tip too checking which props can be set! Thanks

Comment: this doesn't work for me, if I do a getprop immediately after setprop I still get "us". Any idea why?

Comment: @AlexandruCristescu This is on an emulator?

Comment: It might be necessary to use elevated privileges, i.e.: Start the shell using `adb shell`, `su`, and then try what @EspenRiskedal proposes in his post. Then it worked for me—without super-user privileges it did not.

Comment: This doesn't update the `Configuration` dimension `mcc`, which is seemingly what the Resources system uses to identify an alternative resource with an MCC qualifier. Using logging, I see `Configuration.mcc=310`, `TelephonyManager.getSimOperator()='40401'`. I created a resource file ` values-mcc404/values.xml` and was hoping to test the resource override for MCC 404.

Comment: Fine! Thanks so much!

Comment: setprop: failed to set property 'gsm.operator.iso-country' to 'no'

Comment: The latest version of the Android emulator does not have 'su', so this no longer works.

Answer (score 3):

I have observed that value for this properties varies in some API level. I have tried to address this issue.

You can use following command to change the value on API 26:

1. `adb shell`
2. `su`
3. `setprop gsm.operator.numeric 280701`

**Note:** Some emulators require restart.

On some emulators the property can be different name

You can find the property name as follows:

1. `adb shell`
2. `getprop`

It will give you data similar to following:

```
...
[dalvik.vm.lockprof.threshold]: [500]
[dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file]: [/data/anr/traces.txt]
[dalvik.vm.usejit]: [true]
[dalvik.vm.usejitprofiles]: [true]
[debug.atrace.tags.enableflags]: [0]
[debug.force_rtl]: [0]
[dev.bootcomplete]: [1]
[drm.service.enabled]: [true]
[gsm.current.phone-type]: [1]
[gsm.defaultpdpcontext.active]: [true]
[gsm.network.type]: [LTE]
[gsm.nitz.time]: [1524141151210]
[gsm.operator.alpha]: [Android]
[gsm.operator.iso-country]: [us]
[gsm.operator.isroaming]: [false]
[gsm.operator.numeric]: [310260]
[gsm.sim.operator.alpha]: [Android]
[gsm.sim.operator.iso-country]: [us]
[gsm.sim.operator.numeric]: [310260]
[gsm.sim.state]: [READY]
[gsm.version.baseband]: [1.0.0.0]
[gsm.version.ril-impl]: [android reference-ril 1.0]
[hwservicemanager.ready]: [true]
[init.svc.adbd]: [running]
[init.svc.audio-hal-2-0]: [running]
[init.svc.audioserver]: [running]
[init.svc.bootanim]: [stopped]
[init.svc.camera-provider-2-4]: [running]
[init.svc.cameraserver]: [running]
...
```

Search for `numeric` by copying the output in text file. Get the property name and use `setprop <property name> <new MCC MNC>`

You can also use `getProp` to verify whether the value has been changed.

Comment: The latest version of the Android emulator does not have 'su', so this no longer works.

Comment: su: inaccessible or not found

Answer (score 0):

On emulator: go to Settings->WireLess and Network->Mobile Network->Access Point Names. Try changing MCC value in the set APN and then try your code.

Comment: Good idea, but it didn't work.  When I tried this the APN disappeared from the list, and my application couldn't access the network anymore.

Comment: Well,in my case the APN did disappear and I got: "No Network connection" when I fired up the browser. But when I okayed the alert, I was able to surf the internet. Strange behavior. Anyways, you can do a "Reset to Default" on the APN page and get your earlier APN back.

Answer (score 0):

Do know that relying on an MCC is not always correct in every country. Digicell for instance use one MCC+MNC in several countries. Also understand that the whole idea of an MCC is rather ludicrous from an network point of view. It is rather irrelevant to know if you're in Germany or in the Netherlands if both times you're on T-Mobile with an AT&T handset.

Comment: While I totally agree with said, this does not answer the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible to change MCC/MNC via settings on the Android emulator, every time this is attempted the preconfigured "T-Mobile" APN will disappear from the list and network connectivity is lost. I've even had the emulator spontaneously reboot after a change.

The programmatic way doesn't work either, the APN will disappear right after:

```
root@generic_x86:/ # content update --uri content://telephony/carriers/ --bind name:s:'TheAPN' --bind apn:s:apn.operator.net --bind numeric:i:12345 --bind user:s: --bind password:s: --bind server:s: --bind proxy:s: --bind mmsproxy:s: --bind mmsc:s: --bind type:s: --bind mcc:i:123 --bind mnc:i:45 --bind current:i:1 --where _id=1
```

It could be possible by hacking the emulator in the same ways that allow to change the [MSISDN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16175928/810448) or [IMEI](http://blog.thecobraden.com/2012/10/building-better-emulator-part-1.html), though.

Answer (score 0):

Changing MCC+MNC in the emulator can only be done with ADB. To change the MCC+MNC in the emulator, connect to ADB do the following

```
adb -s 127.0.0.1:53001 shell
```

Then put your country code there. 23801 is danish coutry code.

```
setprop persist.<name of the emulator>.mccmnc 23801
```

For Droid4X emulator, it is

```
setprop persist.droid4x.mccmnc 23801
```

Reboot the emulator.

Comment: The property is set, but I don't think this works - TelephonyManager does not read this property when returning getSimCountryIso() afaik