# Is it possible to simulate CellID and/or LAC changes through the android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am building an app that works on LAC and CellIDs coming in through `TelephonyManager.getCellLocation`.

this all works fine when on my phone, but I would like to test some stuff in the emulator. Is it possible to send simulated CellIDs and LACs to the emulator through a terminal (or any other means) so I can test the CellID changes and LAC changes.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637606/how-do-i-change-the-mobile-country-code-mcc-in-the-android-emulator