# Changing the SimCountryIso in Android Emulator API 24 Nougat

Tags: android, adb, appium, android-7.0-nougat

Till now we are using this approach [How do I change the Mobile Country Code (MCC) in the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637606/how-do-i-change-the-mobile-country-code-mcc-in-the-android-emulator) to change the sim country value. Since we run our emulated devices with API 24 the Emulator stays in default us country code.

This is how we run it within gradle:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperties = System.getProperties()
    systemProperty "buildDir", "${buildDir}"
    systemProperty "file.encoding", "UTF8"

    beforeTest {
        logger.info "restoring android emulator SIM country to AT"
        exec {
            commandLine "bash", "-c", "source ~/.bash_profile && adb -e shell setprop gsm.sim.operator.iso-country at
            ignoreExitValue true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me it works when I run this command as root user on AVD version 24+:

```
adb shell su root setprop gsm.sim.operator.iso-country at
```