# How do I change the phone number of an android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

The question is quite simple; How do I change the phonenumber of an android emulator?

[Another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867286/change-phone-number-in-emulator-android-development) has discussed the same issue, however, only a link to the documentation whas given. As far as I know, the refered piece of documentation does not describe how you could change the devices phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter `android_id` (other phone ID) into providers table. Check this [detecting an emulator, and getting around detection](http://strazzere.com/blog/?tag=android_id).

Here is another [Android emulators with phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746597/running-several-android-emulators-with-different-phone-numbers) on this topic.

Comment: The android_id isn't a phone number. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DanGetz If you are debugging by connecting phone, then it would be phone number. Read the question linked, hope that helps!

Comment: No, it would not be a [phone number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_number). It would be the phone's Android device ID.

Comment: @DanGetz: Ah,  I see what you are stressing for "phone number", Ok, "phone ID" (I understand phone number represents xxx-xx-xxxx, but that is not what I meant in this context)

Answer (score 0):

Without recompiling, the port number that the emulator is running on controls the last 4 digits of the phone number. The first 7 digits can changed by editing the emulator-arm or emulator-x86 binaries in a hex editor.

More info here: http://vrt-blog.snort.org/2013/04/changing-imei-provider-model-and-phone.html